# my form submit does not work what is the problem that prevents it from working?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I have a problem sending my form submit and I do not know what the problem is.

I have already tried the debugging but it does not work can someone help me found the solution please?

this is my jsp page :

```
  <%@page import="controller.Cnx"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<%

Connection c=Cnx.getcnx();
Statement st=c.createStatement();
ResultSet re=st.executeQuery("select * from place");
Statement st2=c.createStatement();
ResultSet re2=st2.executeQuery("select * from local");
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Interface locataire</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Sufee Admin - HTML5 Admin Template">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/themify-icons/css/themify-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/selectFX/css/cs-skin-elastic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Css_acceuil_locataire.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3fd0d5f24.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>
    <body>



        <aside id="left-panel" class="left-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-default" style="flex-flow:column wrap;">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gestion parkings</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand hidden" href="./"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Logo"></a>
            </div>

            <div id="main-menu" class="main-menu collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-right: 80px;"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right" style="margin-right: 10px;" selected></i>Réservation</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-right: 80px;"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right" style="margin-right: 10px;" selected></i>Liste réservation</a>

                    </li>



                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </aside>



    <nav class="navbar" style="height:70px;" id='nav-proprietaire'>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="Page_de_cnx" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding-left: 1430px; text-transform: uppercase"> <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>Déconnection</a>

                    </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


        <label id="label1">Liste des places disponibles avec leurs emplacements :</label>

        <table class="table table-hover" style="margin-top: 20px;" id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-active">
      <th scope="col">Nom local</th>
      <th scope="col">Numéro place</th>
      <th scope="col">Prix par heure</th>
      <th scope="col">Taille</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>


    </tr>
     </thead>
     <%while(re.next()){%> 
      <tbody id="corps">
     <tr>

            <td scope="row"><%=re.getObject(2)%></td>
            <td><%=re.getObject(3)%></td>
            <td><%=re.getObject(4)%></td>
            <td><%=re.getObject(5)%></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reservation" name="reservermodal" ><i class="fas fa-plus" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>Réserver</a></td>
     </tr>


      <%}%>







  </tbody>

</table>
   <div class="modal" id="reservation">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Information</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="POST" id="f" action='Acceuil_locataire'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Nom du local approprié à la place :</label>
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="nom_localhidden"  name="nom_localhidden">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom_local"  name="nom_local" disabled>


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Numéro place :</label>
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="numeroplacehidden"  name="numeroplacehidden">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numeroplace"  name="numeroplace" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Prix par heure:</label>
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="prixplacehidden"  name="prixplacehidden">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prixplace" placeholder="Entrer le prix de la place" name="prixplace" disabled>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Taille de la place :</label>
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="tailleplacehidden"  name="tailleplacehidden">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tailleplace" placeholder="Entrer la taille de la place" name="tailleplace" disabled>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Votre Cin :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cinlocataire" placeholder="Entrer votre cin" name="cinlocataire" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Heure début de la réservation :</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="heure_debut" placeholder="Entrer l'heure de début" name="heure_debut" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Heure fin de la réservation :</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="heure_fin" placeholder="Entrer l'heure de fin" name="heure_fin" required>

            </div>








      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">

         <div id='divbtnaddplace'>      
             <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paiement" data-dismiss="modal" id='btnreserver' style='vertical-align: 0;  margin-right: 220px;'>Réserver</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button> 

           </div>




      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>    


      <div class="modal" id="paiement">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Information</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" id="f1" action="Acceuil_locataire"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Votre Cin :</label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cin"  name="cin">


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Type paiement :</label>

                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6 select-outline">

                        <select class="mdb-select md-form md-outline colorful-select dropdown-primary btn-lg" style="width: 465px;" name="typepaiement">
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                          <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
                          <option value="Carte bancaire">Carte bancaire</option>
                          <option value="Payonner">Payonner</option>
                        </select>


                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Prix :</label>
                <br>
                <input type='hidden' id='prixtotalhidden' name="prixtotalhidden">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id="prix"  name="prixtotal" style='font-size: 20px; color: red;' disabled="">

            </div>



      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" id="buttonpayer" name="action" value="payer"  style="margin-right: 250px;">Payer</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>

      </div>
      </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


        <script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>

    <script src="vendors/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>


    <script>

        function afficher(e){
   e.preventDefault();//pour inhiber le lien, parce que le bouton .btn est un <a href="#">
   var tr=$(this).closest('tr');

    $('#f .custom-select')
        .html('<option value="'+tr.find('td:eq(0)').text()+'">'+tr.find('td:eq(0)').text()+'</option>');


    $('#nom_local').val(tr.find('td:eq(0)').text());

    $('#numeroplace').val(tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());

    $('#prixplace').val(tr.find('td:eq(2)').text());

    $('#tailleplace').val(tr.find('td:eq(3)').text());



     $('#nom_localhidden').val(tr.find('td:eq(0)').text());

    $('#numeroplacehidden').val(tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());

    $('#prixplacehidden').val(tr.find('td:eq(2)').text());

    $('#tailleplacehidden').val(tr.find('td:eq(3)').text());
}
/* Quand le document est prêt */
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#table1').on('click','#corps .btn',afficher);
});   



    </script>
    <script>
        function recuperer_prix_total(){
            var prixtotal= $('$prixtotal').val();
            $('$prixtotalhidden').val(prixtotal);
        }
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#buttonpayer').on('click',recuperer_prix_total());  
});   

    </script>
    <script>




$('#paiement').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {//quand #myModal s'affiche

    var heure_debut = $("#heure_debut").val(),  
    heure_fin = $("#heure_fin").val(),
    prix=$('#prixplace').val(),
    diff,
    total;
    console.log("prix"+prix);
    console.log('Ouverture du modal...');//vérifies si tu vois cette ligne dans la console quand le modal #myModal est affiché
    if (moment(heure_debut, "HH:mm").isValid() && moment(heure_fin, "HH:mm").isValid()) {
            diff = moment.utc(moment(heure_fin, 'HH:mm').diff(moment(heure_debut, 'HH:mm')));
            console.log("diif = "+diff);
            total=prix *  moment(diff,'HH:mm').hour()+ ( moment(diff,'HH:mm').minutes()/60 );
            console.log(total);
            $("#prix").val(total.toFixed(2)+"  DHS");
 console.log('Ouverture du modal, debut :'+heure_debut,", fin :"+heure_fin);

            console.log("différence :", diff.format('HH:mm'),", hour :",moment(diff,'HH:mm').hour(),
               ", minutes :",moment(diff,'HH:mm').minutes(), 
              ", total :",total.toFixed(2));
   } else 
        console.log("heure invalide !");
    console.log('Ouverture du modal, debut :'+heure_debut,", fin :"+heure_fin);

});



    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my servlet :

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nom_local=request.getParameter("nom_localhidden");

         System.out.println("hello");

        String numeroplace=request.getParameter("numeroplacehidden");
        String prixplace=request.getParameter("prixplacehidden");
        String tailleplace=request.getParameter("tailleplacehidden");
        String cinlocataire=request.getParameter("cinlocataire");
        String heure_debut=request.getParameter("heure_debut");
        String heure_fin=request.getParameter("heure_fin");
        String action=request.getParameter("action");
        DateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String cin=request.getParameter("cin");
        String typepaiement=request.getParameter("typepaiement");
        String prixtotalhidden=request.getParameter("prixtotalhidden");
        Connection c=Cnx.getcnx();
        try{
          if("payer".equals(action)){
            PreparedStatement st=c.prepareStatement("insert into reservation values (null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            st.setString(1, nom_local);
            st.setString(2, numeroplace);
            st.setString(3, prixplace);
            st.setString(4, tailleplace);
            st.setString(5, cinlocataire);
            st.setTime(6, new java.sql.Time(dateformat.parse(heure_debut).getTime()));
            st.setTime(7, new java.sql.Time(dateformat.parse(heure_fin).getTime()) );
            int res=st.executeUpdate(); 
              System.out.println("hello");
             if(res>0){
                 System.out.println("reservation réaliser avec succes");

           }

           else {
                System.out.println("reservation non ajouter");
           }

             PreparedStatement st2=c.prepareStatement("insert into paiement values (null,?,?,?)");
             st2.setString(1, cin);
             st2.setString(2, typepaiement);
             st2.setString(3, prixtotalhidden);
            int res2= st2.executeUpdate();
            if(res2>0){
                 System.out.println("paiement réaliser avec succes");

           }

           else {
                System.out.println("paiement non ajouter");
           }
            }



        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Acceuil_locataire.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

normally I put in the form action = ... and in the button I give it a name and a value and I use them in my servlet.

Normally this technique works on my other projects but here it blocks the form is not send to the servlet and I really do not know what the problem is.

sorry if my question is stupid but it's 1 day I'm stuck on it and i am just a begginner

Help me please !

Comment: You have two form and i don't know which one you are trying to submit. But to submit a from you need to have button type = submit or you can use javascript to submit. I am not able to see any of those in first form.

Comment: I'm trying to put the second form and I already put the type submit for my button you can see that in the second form

Comment: Please post your servlet mapping

Comment: Any console errors? Any server log file errors?

Comment: Can you inspect your webpage on browser? It is giving any error at front-end?

Comment: no there is no error in the console, and yes I can inspect my web page, the problem is that he did not access the servlet because I tested this with a " System.out.println("hello");" but it does not does not appear in the console so he does not have access, and I have not put any access condition consernent the mapping I just gave access to my servlet through the action of my form but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: I found the solution in fact I put a data-dismiss = "modal" which closes the modal before entering the servlet